Change the resolution on a headless Mac Mini server on MacOS Sonoma (arm64)
I have a Mac-Mini 2023 running MacOS Sonoma that runs without display accessed via VNC. In system settings there is no way to change the display resolution. At the moment it shows 1920x1080 but I want to set it to a slightly smaller resolution.
There is an old identical question Force the resolution on a headless mac mini server and a related question How can I set a scaled display resolution from the command-line but all the mentioned free programs or tools do no longer work:
Change resolution apps from App Store only show one resolution, nothing to change:

Any Screen resolution
Display Menu
EasyRes

Other tools:

display_manager.py fails changing the display resolution and again fails to display the error message
cscreen has not been updated for more than 12 years and only exists of Intel CPUs (Bad CPU type in executable).
screen-resolution-switcher (scres) only shows one possible resolution


Buy one of the headless HDMI plugs to make the Mini think it has an actual monitor, then you can change the resolution.
Link to an Amazon search of "headless HDMI"
